# Difficulty understanding Cayley theorem (group theory).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm teaching myself group theory from Dummit and Foote.

The statement of the Cayley theorem is : Every group is isomorphic to a subgroup of some symmetric group.

I am convinced if a given group is finite. What if it is infinite? How can it be isomorphic to a subgroup of a symmetric group? My understanding is that a symmetric group is finite. Could someone clarify this please?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is the symmetric group acting on $G$. Hence the symmetric group in context may be infinite as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetric group is the group of bijections from a set $X$ to itself, with composition as the operation. If $X$ is finite with $n$ elements, then it is identified with $S_n$ as you know. But if $X$ is infinite, the group of bijections still makes sense, and this is what the symmetric group means in the infinite order case.

In proving Cayley's theorem, the argument is that left-multiplication by any fixed element is a bijection $G\to G$, and this is still the case for infinite $G$. This shows that $G$ is a subgroup of all the bijections $G\to G$.

Answer (score 0):

Finite order is not required. The group $G=S_X$ is isomorphic to the group of left-multiplications $L = \{l_g\mid g\in G\}$, where $l_g:G\rightarrow G$ is the left-mult. $l_g(h)=gh$. The isomorphism is given by $g\mapsto l_g$.

Comment: I see. I am used to seeing symmetric groups on a finite number of elements. I was just having a hard time picturing a symmetric group on an uncountable set, say reals. Thanks. I think I understand now.